# mysql inner join two tables with month matching

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a two tables in MySQL and both tables in same database.
table name **data**

```
| service   | count     | date | 
--------------------------------------
| bugss     | 375   | 2022-01-01 05:00:00.00000 
| fromsite  | 5     | 2022-02-01 05:00:00.00000 
| kbocetra  | 100   | 2022-01-05 07:00:00.00000
```

tried for data table

```
SELECT SUM(`count`) AS Alertcount,
DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') AS Month,
FROM data
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m')
```

output:

```
January  | 475
February | 5
```

another table name **pd**

```
| group | minutes   | projdate | 
-------------------------------- 
gcp     | 145       | 2022-01-01 05:00:00.00000 
azure   | 10        | 2022-02-01 05:00:00.00000 
aws     | 80        | 2022-01-05 07:00:00.00000
```

i tried below command for separate tables, for pd table as below ..which gives output as

```
SELECT SUM(`minutes`) AS Hours,
DATE_FORMAT(`group  `, '%M') AS Month
FROM pd
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`group`, '%Y-%m')
```

output:

```
January  | 225
February | 10
```

and im expected the ouput like below, and total count would be as output of two tables  count/minutes i.e., 475/225
and 5/10.
please help, i red about inner statement, but didn't worked.

| Month | total |
| --- | --- |
| January | 0.78 |
| February | 2 |

Comment: How does 475/225 end up as 0.78?

Comment: sorry @salmon san, while copying did typo mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command and see the results.

```
SELECT
    a.`Month`,
    a.`Hours` / b.`Alertcount` as 'total'
FROM
    (
SELECT
    SUM( `minutes` ) AS Hours,
    DATE_FORMAT( `group  `, '%M' ) AS 'Month' 
FROM
    pd 
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT( `group`, '%Y-%m' ) 
    ) a
    INNER JOIN (
SELECT
    SUM( `count` ) AS Alertcount,
    DATE_FORMAT( `date`, '%M' ) AS 'Month' 
FROM
DATA 
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT( `date`, '%Y-%m' ) 
    ) b ON a.`Month` = b.`Month`
```

Answer (score 0):

When selecting the tables you can use the division operator as you can see [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-division-operator.php).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).